# twilio whatsapp image download - 401 error

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am trying out twilio<->whatsapp via sandbox testing free trial.

I am able to receive text messages from whatsapp just fine in my flask server.  But when I receive an image from whatsapp I get a MediaUrl0 which when fetched gives me back a 401 error xml with 20003 twilio error code. The MediaUrl0 itself is a long api.twilio.com url.

I thought authentication wouldn't be required for incoming images and the whatsapp image url is a public aws url? Anyway even when I tried to set client = Client(testing_account_sid, testing_auth_token), it didn't work.

Any idea what I am doing wrong

thanks
Vulcanoid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: You might need to use Basic Auth depending on when you [created your account](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/upcoming-security-changes-enforcing-http-authentication-for-media)

It shouldn't be necessary but maybe you are sending an incorrect request. Try running this snippet:

```py
import os
import requests    # ← new import
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

def respond(message):
    response = MessagingResponse()
    response.message(message)
    return str(response)

@app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
def reply():
    sender = request.form.get('From')
    message = request.form.get('Body')
    media_url = request.form.get('MediaUrl0')
    print(f'{sender} sent {message}')
    if media_url:
        r = requests.get(media_url)
        content_type = r.headers['Content-Type']
        username = sender.split(':')[1]  # remove the whatsapp: prefix from the number
        if content_type == 'image/jpeg':
            filename = f'uploads/{username}/{message}.jpg'
        elif content_type == 'image/png':
            filename = f'uploads/{username}/{message}.png'
        elif content_type == 'image/gif':
            filename = f'uploads/{username}/{message}.gif'
        else:
            filename = None
        if filename:
            if not os.path.exists(f'uploads/{username}'):
                os.mkdir(f'uploads/{username}')
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
            return respond('Thank you! Your image was received.')
        else:
            return respond('The file that you submitted is not a supported image type.')
    else:
        return respond('Please send an image!')
```

For more details, check out [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/receive-images-whatsapp-flask-twilio).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes, that post about twilio & flask is exactly what I am following. 
I am not sure why there is an authentication error, should I authenticate to twilio before the request.get(media_url)?  That returns something like:
b"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>20003</Code><Message>Authenticate</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003</MoreInfo><Status>401</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>"

And the media url is in the format: https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/......./Messages/....../Media/.....

Comment: Is it because I am using a sandbox trial? I haven't paid for any twilio access yet and am trying out the sandbox with ngrok and flask.

Comment: I just tested in with the Sandbox and it works as expected. Maybe there's a issue with your code. It should work when you open the mediaUrl0 in your browser

Comment: Thanks. In the browser trying the mediaurl0 pops up a sign into api.twilio.com username/password popup asking me to sign in.

Comment: Usually you can enter your account sid (for username) and the auth token (for password) when you see this prompt. However, I do believe you're querying the wrong URL as the URL should be publicly accessible.

Comment: It worked when I add an auth header containing sid and auth token to my request. Surprised that it required authentication. Anyhow it works . Thanks.

Comment: Great. I leave this [change log item](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/upcoming-security-changes-enforcing-http-authentication-for-media) here for context in case someone else comes here